# Error: terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6

Tags: c++, threadabortexception

I am making a hot potato game that deals with inheritance. I have a potato class, player class and umpire class.

In calling the toss function within my umpire class I KEEP getting this same error and I can't seem to figure out why: terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6

I went through and found that within umpire::start(), the call to Players.at(randU)->toss(*m) in my for loop is making this error come up. But everything looks fine to me.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

**Umpire.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "potato.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "umpire.h"
#include "PRNG.h"
using namespace std;

// Declare globally
int gamecount=1;

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
bool first=false; // False if set has not started
PRNG rplayer;

// UMPIRE CONSTRUCTOR-------------------------------------------------------------------
Umpire::Umpire( Player::PlayerList &players ){
   Players=players;
   cout<<"\tMashed POTATO will go off after ";
   cout.flush();
   m=new Mashed(Players.size()-1);
   cout << " tosses" << endl;
   cout.flush();
   cout <<"\tFried POTATO will go off after 5 tosses" << endl;  
   cout.flush();
   f=new Fried(5);}

// UMPIRE DESTRUCTOR-------------------------------------------------------------------
Umpire::~Umpire(){  
    delete m;
    delete f;}


// UMPIRE START------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Umpire::start(){
int randU;
int gameCount=1; // Keeps track of sets

// Check if you are at the end of the list.
if(Players.size()==1){
    // Who won?
    cout << Players.at(0)->getId() << "wins the Match!" << endl;
    cout.flush();}
else{

// Print output for sets----------------------------------------------------------------
// See which potato is being used in the set
if(gameCount%2!=0){ 
    cout << "Set " << gameCount << "-\tUser (mashed) [";
    cout.flush();}
else{ 
    cout << "Set " << gameCount << "-\tUser (fried) [";
    cout.flush();}
gameCount++; // increase gamecount
// Outputting players left in the set
for(unsigned int i=0;i<Players.size();i++){
    cout<<Players.at(i)->getId();}
cout <<"]: ";
cout.flush();

//Start Tossing--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    randU=rplayer(Players.size()-1);
    // Output A(id) or R(id)
    if (randU%2==0){
        cout<<"A("<<randU<<"), ";
        cout.flush();}
    else{
        cout<<"R("<<randU<<"), ";
        cout.flush();}
    if(first==false){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<Players.size(); i++){
            if(Players.at(i)->getId()==Players.at(randU)->toss(*m)){
                Players.erase(Players.begin()+i);
                cout << "Eliminated: "<< i << endl;
                cout.flush();}
        }
        first=true;
        f->reset();
        start();
    }
    else{
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<Players.size(); i++){
            if(Players.at(i)->getId()==Players.at(randU)->toss(*f)){
                Players.erase(Players.begin()+i);
                cout << "Eliminated: "<< i << endl;
                cout.flush();}
        } 
        first=false;
        m->reset();
        start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"
#include "potato.h"
#include "PRNG.h"
using namespace std;

// GLOBAL DECLARATIONS--------------------------------------------------------------------
PRNG randP;

// PLAYER CONSTRUCTOR---------------------------------------------------------------------
Player::Player(unsigned int id, Player::PlayerList &players){
    pid=id;
    Players=players;
    lrpFLAG=false;}

// getId() returns the player's id--------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int Player::getId(){
        return pid;}

// RNPlayer Constructor-------------------------------------------------------------------
RNPlayer::RNPlayer( unsigned int id, Player::PlayerList &players ) : Player(id,players){}

// TOSS FUNCTION--------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int RNPlayer::toss( Potato &potato ){
unsigned int randnum;
if(potato.countdown()){ return getId(); }
    for(;;){    
        randnum=randP(Players.size()-1);
        if (randnum%2==0){
            cout<<"A("<<randnum<<"), ";
            cout.flush();}
        else{
            cout<<"R("<<randnum<<"), ";
            cout.flush();}
        // If our randomly selected player is not the current player...
        if(Players.at(randnum)->getId()!=getId()){
            break;}
    }   
return Players.at(randnum)->toss(potato);
}

// LRPlayer Constructor-------------------------------------------------------------------
LRPlayer::LRPlayer( unsigned int id, Player::PlayerList &players ) : Player(id,players){}

// TOSS FUNCTION
unsigned int LRPlayer::toss( Potato &potato ){
    unsigned int current; // current player
    // Find who our current player is
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<Players.size(); i++){
        if(Players.at(i)->getId()==getId()){
            current=i;
            cout<<"A("<<i<<"), ";}
    }
    // if timer hasn't gone off yet...
    if(potato.countdown()!=true){
    // if this is the FIRST toss, we want to toss left
        if(lrpFLAG==false){
            if(current==0){
                lrpFLAG=true;
                (Players.at(Players.size()-1))->toss(potato);}
            else{
                lrpFLAG=true;
                (Players.at(current-1))->toss(potato);}
            }
        else{
            if(current==Players.size()-1){
                lrpFLAG=false;
                (Players.at(0))->toss(potato);}
            else{
                lrpFLAG=false;
                (Players.at(current+1))->toss(potato);}
            }
        }
    return (Players.at(current))->getId();
}
```

**Main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include "potato.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "umpire.h"
#include "PRNG.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int p = 5;
    int tmp;
    unsigned int s;
    PRNG prng1;
    prng1.seed(1234567890);
    // Parse the command line arguments
    switch ( argc ) {
        case 3:
            tmp=atoi(argv[1]);
            s=atoi(argv[2]);
            prng1.seed(s);
            if(tmp<2 || tmp>20){
                cout << "Player must be between 2 and 20 inclusive" << endl;
                    return 0;}
            else{
                p = atoi(argv[1]);}
        }
    // Creating list of players.
    Player::PlayerList players;
    for(int i=0; i<p; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            players.push_back(new LRPlayer(i,players));}
        else{               
            players.push_back(new RNPlayer(i,players));}
        }

//for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++){
//  cout << "Player at " << i << " id: " << players.at(i)->getId() << endl;}

// How many players?----------------------------------------------------------------------
cout << p << " players in the match" << endl;

// Construct an UMPIRE--------------------------------------------------------------------
Umpire u(players);

// Start the game!------------------------------------------------------------------------
u.start();

}
```

Also note: PRNG.h is a class that generates a random number. so PRNG prng1; int rand=prng1(#) generates a random number between 0 and #.

**ALSO:**
The problem is occurring when i call my toss function. I'm not out of range because when i try to call Players.at(randU)->getID() i don't get any errors at all. Could it be that i can't reach the toss function for that player?I'm thinking it has to do with something im pointing to or memory. I first make a PlayerList players in my main.cc and push_back players alternating between the two. But each player also takes in a list. Maybe I'm running into errors involved with this?

Thanks! Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/. And also run your program in a debugger, it will help you locate _where_ the exception is thrown, and let you examine variables to see why it might have happened.

Comment: For starters have a look at what the exception is. It is almost certainly an out of range error, though. So print the calues of the vectors's size and the argument to `at()` and verify is in the expected range.

Comment: how do i figure out what the exception is?

Comment: Generally you'd use something like `try { code_throwing_goes_here(); } catch (std::exception const& e) { std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; } catch (...) { std::cout << "unknown exception\n"; }`

Answer (score 0):

The exception thrown must be std::out_of_range. The random number you are generating must be higher than the number of elements in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

`randU` must be re-generated after `Players.erase()` is called. Otherwise it will go out of range.
Or you should break the loop as:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<Players.size(); i++){
            if(Players.at(i)->getId()==Players.at(randU)->toss(*f)){
                Players.erase(Players.begin()+i);
                cout << "Eliminated: "<< i << endl;
                cout.flush();
                break; // BREAK HERE as randU now can be greater than (Players.size() - 1)
            }
        }
```

Comment: randU does get regenerated after erase because i recurse on start() again. However, doesn't erase shrink the vector for me anyways? so when i call randU I won't run into that problem again?

Comment: `randU` does not change during the `for(unsigned int i=0; i<Players.size(); i++){` execution. So you have a chance of `randU` being greater than Players.size()-1 once the `Players.erase(Players.begin()+i)` have executed

Comment: Ok that is a problem thanks! However I'm still running into the issue with calling toss itself...

Comment: Please elaborate on that `toss()` call issue. It would also help if you could reduce your code size or have the whole source available for download as an archive.